# Interpolation techniques predicting negative values in a column with positive values

Tags: python, missing-data, scipy, interpolation

I tried different interpolation techniques & for some numeric columns with only positive values the interpolation techniques: Polynomial, Cubic Spline & Radial Basis are predicting negative values.

How can this issue be fixed? I'm using the interpolation feature in my AutoML production application in which user gets to choose a technique of his/her choice to impute missing values. How should negative values be dealt in such cases?